# Singleton class object referenced by null

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have a singleton class and its instance is referenced in many places in my project. Now I see one such place where the singleton instance is assigned with NULL reference.

Questions are: 1. Will it point to null reference rest of the places? 2. If this is the case, how can I avoid this?

Here is the code snippet.

```
public enum Test {
   INSTANCE;
       public void fun(){
       System.out.println("hello");
   }  
}

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test test = Test.INSTANCE;
       test.fun();
       test = null;
       test.fun();
   }
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "at the one place the instance is assigned with null reference"? It would be easier to help you if you'd give an example - which would also show you what the behaviour is, of course.

Comment: No, it won't point to null at other places.

Answer (score 2):

No, only the local variable `test` in `main` is set to null.

`Test.INSTANCE` still points to the single global instance. Since it is an enum, you can't even force `Test.INSTANCE` to be null.

---

But consider the following (anti-)example, of how the static reference could be reset to null:

```
public class Test {
   public static Test INSTANCE = new Test();

   public void fun(){
       System.out.println("hello");
   }  
}

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test test = Test.INSTANCE;
       test.fun();
       test = null; // test is null, but Test.INSTANCE still points to the global instance
       Test.INSTANCE = null; // now even Test.INSTANCE is null
   }
}
```